# How to make SEO dynamic with react JS hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo

My question is this:

I have a website made in react JS.
The site is currently in production and I want to develop dynamic SEO.
Each page generates an SEO.
Currently I have this code there:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <title>MyWebSite</title>
    <meta name="description" lang="fr" content="MyWebsite" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wish to have in the root div all my *HTML* code to promote my SEO. Moreover, thanks to react-helmet, I wish to promote a dynamic SEO.

Finally, my site is finished in terms of development.
I do not wish to redevelop everything.

I use: *Redux-saga*, *React-Helmet*, *React Hook*, *Styled-Components*.

What do you advise me?

Regards.

Comment: You need to use PHP or a similar server-side solution to serve the index file instead, and insert SEO meta tags based on the url (use url rewriting). The reason for that is that most search engines will not run JS code; all they will see when crawling your domain is the above HTML, and only that. So you need to serve a dynamic document already containing the SEO tags. This cannot be done with client-side JS.

Comment: Ok, i have a back API who is running with symfony 5 api-plateform, can i use it ?

Comment: I guess; try renaming your `index.html` to `index.php` and see if it still loads.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain me why ?

Comment: You can also use server-side rendering with React, but you need to do your own research. This isn't a free tutorial site, sorry.

Comment: I'm just asking you to explain me why it is recommanded to renaming my index.html to index.php Oo.

Comment: I have no idea what your skill level is. Anyway, renaming the built index.html file to index.php is a very basic test that checks whether your server is set up to run PHP scripts. If your API is on the same server, we can assume it is; you'll still need to rename it to index.php and add PHP code that adds URL based meta tags to its <head> though.